# Поиск библиотек для редактирования аудиофайлов (работающих на всех платформах) python 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Постановка задачи:

Вход: файл(ы) в форматах .wav, .mp3
Реализовать утилиту для редактирования аудиофайлов с возможностью ускорения, замедления, разреза, склейки и т.п.

Вопрос: какие библиотеки подойдут для реализации данных функций? Важно, чтобы модули не решали существенную часть задачи, т.е. как я понял, мне нужны библиотеки, дающие возможность представить аудиофайл в виде какого-то массива данных?

Comment: http://www.portaudio.com

Comment: [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: gstreamer, ffmpeg, qt